# Qt Can't get data from QJsonObject

Tags: json, qt

I have this code, which should get country info from this page(http://ipinfo.io/json) :

```
{
QByteArray rawData;
QString countryIp;
if (rep->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    rawData = rep->readAll();
QJsonDocument jsonResponse(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));
QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
countryIp = jsonObject["country"].toString();
qDebug() << countryIp;
}
```

But actually all I got from this code is a blank space. I can't find where is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a `QJsonDocument` and convert it to other types without verifying that the data is valid/not empty.

```
QString readJsonData(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QByteArray rawData;
    QString countryIp;

    //return if there was an error
    if (rep->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        return countryIp;
    rawData = rep->readAll();

    QJsonDocument jsonResponse(QJsonDocument::fromJson(rawData));
    //Check that the JSON is valid and can be converted to QJsonObject
    if (jsonResponse.isNull() || !jsonResponse.isObject())
        return countryIp;

    QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
    //And finally check that it contains the value you need
    if (!jsonObject.contains("country")
        return countryIp;
    countryIp = jsonObject["country"].toString();
        qDebug() << countryIp;
    }
    return countryIp;
}
```

You basically just need checks as you go converting data to verify that you're not receiving garbage or null/empty objects. Then you can debug through and find where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for help, but after adding all the checks to the code it doesn't stop anywhere and just continues to print blank space.

Comment: Actually it threw me an error: QNetworkReply::error returned ProtocolUnknownError (301)

Comment: And now you've found your problem. :-)

Comment: QtNetwork isn't my area, unfortunately. Do some googling, etc. If you can't find anything, post a new question.